# Data being incorrectly written or read to HDFS from spark streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming process that consumes in streaming data from a kafka topic into a `JavaPairDStream` object, and I want to store this data in HDFS. I have tried two approaches, both of which kind of work, but also have presented issues to me me, and I'm unsure if my issue lies in writing the data to HDFS, or when I read from HDFS.

I am running all this on my local machine, in a windows in environment, using Java.

1. **My first attempt** was iterating through the stream and writing each rdd to hdfs using `jPairRDD.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/test/");`. I get no errors running this, but when I try to read the files back in from the "test" directory, nothing is returned. And when I go to the directory myself to try and view the files using `hdfs dfs -ls /test/`, the files are see are `/test/_SUCCESS` and `/test/part-0000` or similar.
2. **My second attempt** (and the current working one) was using `jPairDStream.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://localhost:9000/test/", "txt");`. This works, and I can see the files listed in the "test" directory in HDFS, but when I try to read them back in, there is exactly twice as much data as there should be. 
   I have found the reason for this being that the data has parenthesis' around it for some reason, and the closing parenthesis is on a separate line in the rdd when I read it from HDFS.

In the case of example 2, my **input data** looks like this

```
key, <message msgTime="07-9-2018 15:49:13" mountPoint="HKWS_32" msgLength="107" msgType="1115">0wBrRbAAc7iiQgAg8AAAAAAAAAAgAQEAf95g3v/8fXDoL+FAif+0ENAhcEqGww2lGzsbmjfscJgMbwA6sAEI6h8CoIbU4ikng4eYDrYAQGxf/////gDHLS3K+y6sgdkDwiTBXUK5hgj7R/aP5ggAAIA=</message>
```

And then the **returned data** from hdfs looks like this:

```
(key, <message msgTime="07-9-2018 15:49:13" mountPoint="HKWS_32" msgLength="107" msgType="1115">0wBrRbAAc7iiQgAg8AAAAAAAAAAgAQEAf95g3v/8fXDoL+FAif+0ENAhcEqGww2lGzsbmjfscJgMbwA6sAEI6h8CoIbU4ikng4eYDrYAQGxf/////gDHLS3K+y6sgdkDwiTBXUK5hgj7R/aP5ggAAIA=</message>

)
```

So the rdd has an extra entry containing `)`. I have no idea why this is the case. I can't tell if this is an issue with how I'm writing the data to HDFS, or how I'm read it from there. My code is below for all my classes. Can anyone help me identify why this is the case? My code below will have both of my attempts in it.

**Spark class that consumes streaming data from kafka and writes it to hdfs**

```
public class FatStreamProcessing implements Runnable, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FatStreamProcessing.class);

    static Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    private static final String inTopic = "fatTopicIn";
    private static final Streamery streamery = new Streamery();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        //Set logging level for console
        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);

        //Set spark context to use all cores and batch interval of 1 second and the job name
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("SampleSparkKafkaStreamApp");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(1));

        setupConsumerProperties();

        //Topic the process listens to
        Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList(inTopic);

        //Create DStream that subscribes to the list of Kafka topics
        final JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
                KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                        jssc,
                        LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                        ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams)
                );

        logger.info("Direct Stream created for Fat Stream Consumer");

        //Map kafka input to key value tuple
        JavaPairDStream<String, String> jPairDStream =  stream.mapToPair(
                new PairFunction<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public Tuple2<String, String> call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) throws Exception {
                        return new Tuple2<>(record.key(), record.value());
                    }
                });

        //Save files to hdfs
        //This is the first attempt (see streamery class for implementation)
        streamery.saveToHDFS(jPairDStream);

        //This is the second attempt  
       jPairDStream.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("hdfs://localhost:9000/test/", "txt");

        try {
            jssc.start();
            jssc.awaitTermination();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Configure kafka consumer parameters
     * Example taken from KafkaConsumer documentation
     */
    private static void setupConsumerProperties() {
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "test");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class);
    }
}
```

Ignore this class name, it was originally meant to stream data to more kafka consumers. Now it just stores data to hdfs

**Class that tries to stores files in HDFS for 1st attempt.**

```
public class Streamery {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Streamery.class);

    private static Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    private static int ack_sum = 0;
    private static int brs_sum = 0;
    static int totalInHDFS = 0;

    public Streamery() {

    }

    public void saveToHDFS(JavaPairDStream<String, String> jPairDStream) {
        jPairDStream.foreachRDD(jPairRDD -> {
            jPairRDD.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/test/");
            totalInHDFS += jPairRDD.count();
            logger.info("Saved " + totalInHDFS + " files to hdfs");
        });

    }

    /*
    public void saveToHDFS2(JavaPairDStream<String, String> javaPairDStream) {
        javaPairDStream.foreachRDD(jPairRDD -> {
            jPairRDD.foreach(rdd -> {
                totalInHDFS++;
               System.out.println("RDD conatins: " + rdd._2);
               System.out.println("Total saved to HDFS: " + totalInHDFS);
            });
        });
    }*/
}
```

**Class to read in data from HDFS**

```
public class ReadHDFS {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-M-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    private static final SimpleDateFormat FILE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMdd_HHmmss");

    static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        //FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("hdfsMessages" + FILE_FORMAT.format(new Date()) + ".xml");

        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("TempReadHDFS");

        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/test/*");


        List<String> temp = textFile.collect();

        temp.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));

        System.out.println("Total number of files in HDFS: " + textFile.count());

    }
}
```